# How accurately does the 2009 movie "City of Life and Death" depict the actual Japanese victory march of Nanking in 1937?

Tags: historical-accuracy, city-of-life-and-death

From the 2009 film *City of Life and Death*, footage of the Japanese victory march of Nanking in 1937 can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cufG2Dlxvk) on YouTube.

I was just wondering, how accurately does the movie depict the actual Japanese victory march of Nanking in 1937?

Comment: The top comments below the video might answer your question.